# how can the sub-menu slide down from the sidebar when i just take my cursor to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made a sidebar on which if i click on any option than submenu slides down,but now i want if i just take my cursor to the menu option ,without clicking the sub-menu it should slides down
js code:

```
 $('.subMenu > a').click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var subMenu = $(this).siblings('ul');
        var li = $(this).parents('li');
        var subMenus = $('#sidebar li.subMenu ul');
        var subMenus_parents = $('#sidebar li.subMenu');
        if(li.hasClass('open'))
        {
            if(($(window).width() > 768) || ($(window).width() < 479)) {
                subMenu.slideUp();
            } else {
                subMenu.fadeOut(250);
            }
            li.removeClass('open');
        } else 
        {
            if(($(window).width() > 768) || ($(window).width() < 479)) {
                subMenus.slideUp();         
                subMenu.slideDown();
            } else {
                subMenus.fadeOut(250);          
                subMenu.fadeIn(250);
            }
            subMenus_parents.removeClass('open');       
            li.addClass('open');    
        }
    });
    var ul = $('#sidebar > ul');
    $('#sidebar > a').click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var sidebar = $('#sidebar');
        if(sidebar.hasClass('open'))
        {
            sidebar.removeClass('open');
            ul.slideUp(250);
        } else 
        {
            sidebar.addClass('open');
            ul.slideDown(250);
        }
    });

});`
```

Comment: Can you make a demo here http://jsfiddle.net So that we can know what and where the problem is?

Comment: user the [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) event instead of the click to trigger the function.

Comment: Thank you MrD and even mouseover is working.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace with the following code..

```
$('.subMenu > a').on("mouseover",function(e){});
```